# Using SQLAlchemy to make a single combined relationship from two other unrelated ones

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have 3 models:

- `Collection`: it contains `Categories` and `Scripts`
- `Category`: it contains `Scripts`, and has a parent `Collection`
- `Script`: it can have multiple `Collections` and `Categories`

The association tables are `collection_script` and `category_script`.

I want to get all `Collections` that a script belongs to. That means the result of both `Script.collections` and `Script.categories.collection`.

I currently have this which has the correct logic but obviously doesn't work for queries:

```
class Script(Base):
    ...
    @hybrid_property
    def all_collections(self):
        """Return a list of collections that contain the script."""
        return set([category.collection for category in self.categories] + self.collections)
```

I would like to create a `relationship` for that so I can directly query the models. Something like this:

```
class Script(Base):
    ...
    all_collections = relationship(
        'Collection',
        primaryjoin=???,
        viewonly=True, uselist=True,
    )
```

Here's a minimal version of the database:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, Table, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
Base = declarative_base()

category_scripts_association = Table('category_script', Base.metadata,
    Column('script_id', Integer, ForeignKey('script.id')),
    Column('category_id', Integer, ForeignKey('category.id'))
)

collection_scripts_association = Table('collection_script', Base.metadata,
    Column('script_id', Integer, ForeignKey('script.id')),
    Column('collection_id', Integer, ForeignKey('collection.id'))
)

class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'category'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    collection_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('collection.id'))

    collection = relationship('Collection', back_populates='categories')
    scripts = relationship('Script', secondary=category_scripts_association, back_populates='categories')

    def __repr__(self): return self.name

class Collection(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'collection'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    categories = relationship('Category', back_populates='collection')
    scripts = relationship('Script', secondary=collection_scripts_association, back_populates='collections')

    def __repr__(self): return self.name

class Script(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'script'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    categories = relationship('Category', secondary=category_scripts_association, back_populates='scripts')
    collections = relationship('Collection', secondary=collection_scripts_association, back_populates='scripts')

    @hybrid_property
    def all_collections(self):
        """Return a list of collections that contain the script."""
        return set([category.collection for category in self.categories] + self.collections)

# Setup for testing
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
collection1 = Collection(name='Collection 1')
collection2 = Collection(name='Collection 2')
category1 = Category(name='Category 1', collection=collection1)
category2 = Category(name='Category 2', collection=collection1)
category3 = Category(name='Category 3', collection=collection2)
script1 = Script(name='Script 1')
script2 = Script(name='Script 2')
script3 = Script(name='Script 3')

category1.scripts.append(script1)
category1.scripts.append(script2)
category2.scripts.append(script2)
collection1.scripts.append(script1)
collection2.scripts.append(script2)
category3.scripts.append(script3)

session.add(collection1)
session.commit()
```

And here's some code to test what I'm after

```
# Expected:
# script1.all_collections == [collection1]
# script2.all_collections == [collection1, collection2]
# script2.all_collections == [collection2]

for script in session.execute(select(Script)).scalars():
    if script.name == 'Script 1':
        expected = [collection1]
    if script.name == 'Script 2':
        expected = [collection1, collection2]
    if script.name == 'Script 3':
        expected = [collection2]
    valid = set(expected) == set(script.all_collections) and len(expected) == len(script.all_collections)
    print('Valid 1' if valid else 'Invalid 1', script.name)

stmt = select(Script).where(Script.all_collections.any(Collection.name == 'Collection 1'))
for script in session.execute().scalars():
    if script.name in ('Script 1', 'Script 2'):
        print('Valid 2', script.name)
    else:
        print('Invalid 2', script.name)

stmt = select(Script).where(Script.all_collections.any(Collection.name == 'Collection 2'))
for script in session.execute().scalars():
    if script.name in ('Script 2', 'Script 3'):
        print('Valid 3', script.name)
    else:
        print('Invalid 3', script.name)

stmt = select(Script).where(Script.all_collections.any(Collection.name != 'Collection 2'))
for script in session.execute().scalars():
    if script.name in ('Script 1', 'Script 2'):
        print('Valid 4', script.name)
    else:
        print('Invalid 4', script.name)
```

---

I've attempted making a `hybrid_property` to get the IDs of all the collections, but it always just returns a single ID of `1` when querying it, and the relationship complains about joins. The `select` query is theoretically correct and works in statements.

```
class Script(Base):
    ...
    @hybrid_property
    def all_collection_ids(self):
        return set([category.collection_id for category in self.categories] + self.collections)

    @all_collection_ids.expression
    def all_collection_ids(cls):
        return (
            select(distinct(Collection.id))
            .where(
                or_(
                    Collection.categories.any(Category.scripts.any(Script.id == cls.id)),
                    Collection.scripts.any(Script.id == cls.id),
                )
            )
        )

    all_collections = relationship(
        Collection,
        primaryjoin=lambda: Collection.id.in_(Script.all_collection_ids.expression),
        viewonly=True, uselist=True,
    )

# sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't determine relationship direction for relationship 'Script.all_collections' - foreign key columns are present in neither the parent nor the child's mapped tables
```

I also tried separating out the queries and combining later, but I've realised column properties may only return single values, so the final step of combining the two doesn't work.

```
class Script(Base):
    ...
    collection_ids = column_property(
        select(collection_scripts_association.c.collection_id)
        .where(id == collection_scripts_association.c.script_id)
        .subquery()
    )
    category_collection_ids = column_property(
        select(Collection.id)
        .join(Category)
        .where(id.in_(
            select(category_scripts_association.c.script_id)
            .where(category_scripts_association.c.category_id == Category.id)
        ))
        .subquery()
    )

    all_collection_ids = column_property(
        select(distinct(Collection.id))
        .where(or_(
            Collection.id.in_(collection_ids),
            Collection.id.in_(category_collection_ids),
        ))
    )
```

Trying to combine into a single relationship had the same issue about foreign keys.

```
class Script(Base):
    ...
    all_collections = relationship(
        Collection,
        primaryjoin=or_(
            and_(
                Category.collection_id == Collection.id,
                category_scripts_association.c.category_id == Category.id,
                category_scripts_association.c.script_id == id,
            ),
            and_(
                collection_scripts_association.c.collection_id == Collection.id,
                collection_scripts_association.c.script_id == id,
            ),
        ),
        viewonly=True,
        uselist=True
    )

# sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't determine relationship direction for relationship 'Script.all_collections' - foreign key columns are present in neither the parent nor the child's mapped tables
```

I came across [SQLAlchemy: How can I define a relationship as the union of two other relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175258/sqlalchemy-how-can-i-define-a-relationship-as-the-union-of-two-other-relationsh), but I'm not sure how to apply that here.

---

For a higher level overview, I have a much larger database running on an API, and I have code to automatically construct queries based on parameters given, which works across relationships. Each parameter is joined with `AND` rather than `OR`, so by getting this working I can run `scripts?all_collections=xyz` as a single call rather than two separate calls of `scripts?collections.name=xyz` and `scripts?categories.collections.name=xyz`.